# Training a Viterbi tree parser with NLTK for POS-tagged input

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk

Sorry if my question is basic, but I am fairly new to NLP and am still trying to get a grasp of some concepts.

I wanted to train a tree parser with the UPenn treebank using the implementation of the Viterbi algorithm in the NLTK library. However, I want my parser to take as input already POS-tagged sentences. In other words, *I want it to identify only shallower non-terminal productions*.

With NLTK wrapper for the already trained Stanford parser, this is simply achieved with the useful `tagged_parse` module:

```
from nltk.parser import stanford

stanford_parser = stanford.StanfordParser()
parsed_sentence = stanford_parser.tagged_parse(tagged_sentence)
```

where `tagged_sentence` is a list of tuples containing the tokenized sentence and the respective POS-tag. For example:

```
tagged_sentence = [('hello', 'VB'), ('stack', 'NN'), ('exchange', 'NN')]
```

My question is: **how to implement the equivalent of `tagged_parse` in a NLTK Viterbi parser?**

Note: for training the Viterbi parser I am following [Section 3 of these handout solutions](http://coling.epfl.ch/TP/corr/Parsing-sol.php?lang=en). Other references for training resources in Python would also be appreciated.

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for is called CKY, it finds the highest probability tree (if it exists) for an input sentence and a given PCFG. Here is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298074/extract-probabilities-and-most-likely-parse-tree-from-cyk/50351368#50351368) where I describe the algorithm.
If your input sentence already has part-of-speech tags, initialize the chart with corresponding parsing items with score 0, e.g. `['VB', 0, 1]:0`, `['NN', 1, 2]:0`, `['NN', 2, 3]:0` (instead of using the *scan* rule).

Comment: @mcoav, thank you for the reference. I will check it.